# Problems using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

Regx is not my thing.

I have a large file where I want to replace the following example:

```
<g:id><![CDATA[131614-3XL]]></g:id>
```

should be replace with:

```
<g:id><![CDATA[131614-3XL]]></g:id><g:id2><![CDATA[131614]]></g:id2>
```

Please note that "-3XL" is deleted in id2 and please note that -3XL could be many other combinations. fx. -4XL or -32/32 or -42,5 and so on. But it always starts with -

I have tried using preg_replace but I can figure it out.

Comment: As long as "<g:id><![CDATA[131614-3XL]]></g:id>" doesn't change in the string that you want to replace, you can achieve that using a simple string replace, here is the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Please add your `preg_replace` attempts.

Comment: @MarcelloPerri That won't work. `please note that -3XL could be many other combinations`

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to manipulate XML or HTML. Use `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capture group to grab the number in the CDATA so you can copy it to the replacement without the `-XXX` after it.

```
$result = preg_replace('#<g:id><!\[CDATA\[(\d+)-[^]]+\]\]></g:id>#', '$0<g:id2><![CDATA[$1]]></g:id2>', $string);
```

`$0` is the entire match, `$1` is the number in the CDATA.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/Tbx4jD)

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that you can start with.  You might need to adjust depending upon how much the CDATA content changes.

```
$str = "<g:id><![CDATA[131614-3XL]]></g:id>";
$expected = "<g:id><![CDATA[131614-3XL]]></g:id><g:id2><![CDATA[131614]]></g:id2>";

# Get the first section without the g:id wrapper and without the -3XL section
$post_replace = preg_replace("/^<g:id>(.*?CDATA\[\d+)\-[^\]]+(.*?)<\/g:id>$/","$1$2", $str);

$output = "$str<g:id2>$post_replace</g:id2>";

if ($output == $expected) {
    print "Success\n";
}
```